# UIView Height Change Not Reflected in UI

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I have a UIView with embedded stack views containing labels and imageViews. This UIView is designed to expand in height when the text of one of the labels reaches a certain size. The label is set to lines = 0 and word wrap. I have confirmed that the height changes, but this isn't reflected in the UI.

This is the UIView with a standard size name label:

[image]

This is the UIView with an extended size name label. As you can see the "open" label is cut off:

[image]

This function determines the height of UIView:

```
    func viewHeight(_ locationName: String) -> CGFloat {

    let locationName = tappedLocation[0].name

    var size = CGSize()

    if let font = UIFont(name: ".SFUIText", size: 17.0) {
        let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font]
        size = (locationName as NSString).size(withAttributes: fontAttributes)
    }

    let normalCellHeight = CGFloat(96)
    let extraLargeCellHeight = CGFloat(normalCellHeight + 20.33)

    let textWidth = ceil(size.width)
    let cellWidth = ceil(nameLabel.frame.width)

    if textWidth > cellWidth {
        return extraLargeCellHeight
    } else {
        return normalCellHeight
    }
}
```

And this function applies it:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    annotation = view.annotation as! MKPointAnnotation

    horizontalStackView.addBackground(color: UIColor.black)

    // Add the tapped location to the tappedLocation array
    for location in locations {
        if location.latitude == annotation.coordinate.latitude && location.longitude == annotation.coordinate.longitude {
            tappedLocation.append(location)
        }
    }

    locationView.frame.size.height = viewHeight(tappedLocation[0].name)
    print("locationView height = \(locationView.frame.height)")
    print("locationView x = \(locationView.frame.origin.x)")
    print("locationView y = \(locationView.frame.origin.y)")

    print("Frame height: \(locationView.frame.size.height)")
    print("Frame widthL \(locationView.frame.size.width)")

    YelpClient.sharedInstance().loadImage(tappedLocation[0].imageUrl, completionHandler: { (image) in

        performUIUpdatesOnMain {

            self.thumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            self.thumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = true
            self.thumbnailImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            self.thumbnailImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
            self.thumbnailImageView.image = image

            self.nameLabel.text = self.tappedLocation[0].name
            self.nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.white

            self.priceLabel.text = self.tappedLocation[0].price
            self.priceLabel.textColor = UIColor.white

            self.displayRating(location: self.tappedLocation[0])
        }

        YelpClient.sharedInstance().getOpeningHoursFromID(id: self.tappedLocation[0].id, completionHandlerForOpeningHours: { (isOpenNow, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print("There was an error: \(String(describing: error))")
            }

            if let isOpenNow = isOpenNow {

                performUIUpdatesOnMain {

                    if isOpenNow {
                        self.openLabel.text = "Open"
                        self.openLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
                    } else {
                        self.openLabel.text = "Closed"
                        self.openLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 195/255, green: 89/255, blue: 75/255, alpha: 1.0)
                        self.openLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0, weight: .semibold)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    })
    locationView.isHidden = false
}
```

This print statement indicates the height of the UIView is changing height, but the x and y origins are not changing (the view should extend upwards to accommodate the word wrap in the name label):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual height manipulation doesn't work in autolayout. If you want to increase the height, create an `IBOutlet` to a height constraint and set its `constant` value. You can even animate it.

Comment: The beautiful and simple solution I needed.